# Cannot configure VSCode to compile C code on MacOS

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clang, lldb, grpc-c++

I am trying to set up VS Code on macOS to compile and debug C code.

My environment is:

- OS: macOS `14.2`
- VS Code: `1.86.0`
- Project Folder: `~/Projects/CProjects`
- C header files: `~/Projects/CProjects/includes`
- C Program file: `hello.c`
- Path includes: `/Users/Dave/Projects/CProjects/includes`

This is the `hello.c` source, located in `/Users/dave/Projects/CProjects`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello");
}
```

This is my `launch.json` file:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/calcfreq.c"
        },
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/calcfreq.c",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/calcfreq.c",
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I attempt to use the debugger, I get an error that says:

```
> Unable to start debugging. Program path
> '/Users/dave/Projects/CProjects/calcfreq.c' is missing or invalid.
> 
> LLDB failed with message: Command 'file-exec-and-symbols'. Target
> binary '/Users/dave/Projects/CProjects/calcfreq.c' is invalid. error:
> '/Users/dave/Projects/CProjects/calcfreq.c' doesn't contain any 'host'
> platform architectures: arm64, armv7, armv7f, armv7k, armv7s, armv7m,
> armv7em, armv6m, armv6, armv5, armv4, arm, thumbv7, thumbv7k,
> thumbv7s, thumbv7f, thumbv7m, thumbv7em, thumbv6m, thumbv6, thumbv5,
> thumbv4t, thumb, x86_64, x86_64, arm64, arm64e, arm64, arm64e
> 
> This may occur if the process's executable was changed after the
> process was started, such as when installing an update. Try
> re-launching the application or restarting the machine.
```

How can I fix the `launch.json` file and make the debugger work?

Comment: That's the whole dirty underbelly of vscode. Fantastic editor/IDE, but unless you are familiar with `.json` to begin with, you have an additional learning curve to overcome before you can even get started. That said, it's not that bad. Once you make friends with the config file formats, the information on how-to-configure is readily available. (though I found vscode horribly cumbersome to begin with with different commands and settings buried in different lists, etc...) Start with [Using Clang in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

### Wrong Launch Configuration

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/calcfreq.c" <----- WRONG
        },
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/calcfreq.c", <---- WRONG
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/calcfreq.c", <---- WRONG
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Explanation

In the `program` field, you have mentioned the `calcfreq.c` file.

If you are a new programmer, it does seem that the `.c` file is the "program" but it's the **source code**. The program would be the executable file that is compiled from the `.c` file.

So you can use GCC or some other compiler to compile it.

```bash
gcc calcfreq.c -o output_file
```

And then set the program in the json file as this.

```json
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/output_file",
```

### Sample Launch Config

Here's an example `launch.json` that I use.

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name"            : "c-toolkit launch",
            "type"            : "cppdbg",
            "request"         : "launch",
            "program"         : "your_exe_here", <--- PATH TO YOUR EXE
            "args"            : [],
            "stopAtEntry"     : false,
            "cwd"             : "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment"     : [],
            "externalConsole" : false,
            "MIMode"          : "lldb",
        }
    ]
}
```

You can also try my [VSCode extension: C Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit) to create multi-file C projects with all the files and configurations correctly set up, and also build, run and debug them. It works perfectly on MacOS, Windows and Linux, and more importantly it automatically installs all the required development tools if any are missing. :)