# Visual Studio, clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, computer-science

I am trying to run code in VScode (a simple HelloWorld) and it only gives back " error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". I basically cant execute anything, even though i have also modified the json file to execute c/c++. This is the code I have ran:

Note (I am using a Mac)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;

}
```

And it returns (in terminal):
`ld: open() failed, errno=2 for 'build/tut5_calc2'`

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Things I have tried, and their results:

1.- I tried giving permission to vscode to access my files, I also gave permission to finder to access documents, and putting in the terminal: cd Users/"myusername"/Documents/"Foldername"/"docname"

1.-Result: Previous to the change, it was giving me "permission denied" now that was fixed, but when running the code, it gave me the same error ("error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)")

2.- I tried to, once doing step 1, debbuging and running.

2.- Result: Only "runs" if i debbug and run (if i only "run c file" ) it gives the same clang error 1. However, it only works once and shows the "output" in the debugger but i cant interactuate with it (I cant input), and i have to close VScode, reopen it, and rerun and debugg ...

3.- After searching i found a comment elsewhere saying the problem might have been the "#include", so i eliminated it from the code.

3.-Result:

```
error: call to undeclared library function 'printf' with type 'int (const char *, ...)'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    printf("Hello");
```

Basically, I cant run my code... If anybody knows how to fix this, or how to really run code in VScode,  I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Edit1: I have found my error, it is simple but I believe it will be useful for others who review this post:
Solution:When creating a new c file from scratch in VScode, create a folder called "build". This solves it.

Comment: I've never run stuff directly in VSCode as I am not sure how it works.  How does it know which libraries to link, etc?  You might have more luck using CMake with VSCode.  Even then I have issues with VSCode not being able to see the symbols to give intellisense etc.  I would recommend another editor like Xcode or CLion.

Comment: ```perror 2``` says: ```No such file or directory```. So the linker can't find the object file. I don't know how your build-system works, but could you show the JSON, which defines the build rules? Also you may try to just invoke the compiler directly, but I don't see anything wrong with code.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77943317/cannot-configure-vscode-to-compile-c-code-on-macos/77962031#77962031) on how to compile C code on a Mac. Also give my [VSCode extension: C Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit) a try. It handles all the build and run things using CMake.